# Unable to get name of the sport -from team name in android

Tags: android, facebook, freebase

How  to get the name of the sport from professional sport team name from facebook  .Currently I am using this code :

```
SELECT page_id,name,type FROM page WHERE page_id IN ( SELECT page_id FROM page_fan   WHERE uid=me())
```

I get the name and type but I dont get sport for example if I choose "la lakers" then I dont get Basketball as the sport .How can I get that from either facebook or freebase ? I really appreciate any help .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what "I dont get Basketball as the sport" should mean...? There's no `sport` field in the `page` table.

Comment: Exactly How can I get the name of the sport from the page created for eg.if it is an athlete I can check in freebase for ahlete name and I get the sport he plays .I would like to get the same result for team name.How can I obtain that?

Comment: You posted a FQL which is not at all related to Freebase. So what's the point?

Comment: Is there a way to get sport name from the page of athlete or team in facebook .If its possible then I would choose that option else check in freebase for the respective sport.Thats way.Btw thanks for your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the `categories` field of the `Page` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/#columns), but I don't think this will contain the detail you want.